# Custom zsh completion for a function based on default arguments

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

How can I setup completion for a function, based on existing completion definitions and default arguments.

A simplified example (which could be rewritten as an alias):

```
gpl() {
    git pull origin $@
}
```

This should have the same completion as after `git pull origin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
compdef -e 'words[1]=(git pull origin); service=git; (( CURRENT+=2 )); _git' ggl
```

This massages the `$words`, `$service` and `$CURRENT` vars used by the completion system, and then calls the `_git` completion function.

(Thanks to Mikachu on #zsh).

Comment: What does CURRENT+=2 do?  (this is working for me, just trying to grok)

Comment: @skarface `CURRENT` is the current word being handled, and that increases it by `2` (because we inject them: from `ggl` (1 word) to `git pull origin` (3 words)).